# For loop doesn't regen random string, stays the same

Tags: php, for-loop, random

So I m trying to get a random string generator to work with a for loop. I have gotten it to loop the number of times it should but it refuses to generate a new string per loop. Can someone look at my code and show me where i went wrong? Also there is no way of using unqid so do not mention it please.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $key = $_POST['keysd'];
    if(isset($key) && is_string($key))
    {
        switch($key)
        {       
            case "ksc";
            $algor = "78.0000.".rnumstr(7);
            break;

            case "kpl";
            $algor = "76.0000.".rnumstr(7);
            break;

            case "kfi";
            $algor = "D01EB0A01472".rnumstr(1).strtoupper(ralphstr(3));
            break;
        }

            $sum = $_POST['sum'];
            $alg = $algor;
            if(isset($sum))
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $sum; $i++)
                {
                    echo $alg.'<br/>';
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are `rnumstr` and `ralphstr` doing? can't reproduce the problem without a complete example.

Comment: rnumstr generates a random number string and   ralphstr generates a random alphabetical string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate new $alg per loop's iteration, you must call your switch's code every iteration. Refactor your code:

```
function getRandomValue($key)
{
    switch($key)
    {       
        case "ksc":
            return "78.0000.".rnumstr(7);

        case "kpl":
            return "76.0000.".rnumstr(7);

        case "kfi":
            return "D01EB0A01472".rnumstr(1).strtoupper(ralphstr(3));
    }
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $key = $_POST['keysd'];
    if(isset($key) && is_string($key))
    {
            $sum = $_POST['sum'];
            if(isset($sum))
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $sum; $i++)
                {
                    $alg = getRandomValue($key);
                    echo $alg.'<br/>';
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing a return but not break the cases? this confuses me.

Comment: If you return you exit the function, you don't need break. Do you really have "15+ years of coding experience"..?